# Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-dom'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I have tried yarn add react react-dom but still facing these issues.If anyone can help me with this

```
index.js:1437 D:/ecodocs-admin/node_modules/rc-align/es/Align.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-dom' in 'D:\ecodocs-admin\node_modules\rc-align\es'
console.<computed> @ index.js:1437
index.js:1437 D:/ecodocs-admin/node_modules/rc-animate/es/AnimateChild.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-dom' in 'D:\ecodocs-admin\node_modules\rc-animate\es'
console.<computed> @ index.js:1437
index.js:1437 D:/ecodocs-admin/node_modules/rc-time-picker/es/Select.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-dom' in 'D:\ecodocs-admin\node_modules\rc-time-picker\es'
console.<computed> @ index.js:1437
index.js:1437 D:/ecodocs-admin/node_modules/rc-trigger/es/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-dom' in 'D:\ecodocs-admin\node_modules\rc-trigger\es'
console.<computed> @ index.js:1437
index.js:1437 D:/ecodocs-admin/node_modules/rc-trigger/es/Popup.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-dom' in 'D:\ecodocs-admin\node_modules\rc-trigger\es'
console.<computed> @ index.js:1437
index.js:1437 D:/ecodocs-admin/node_modules/rc-util/es/Portal.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-dom' in 'D:\ecodocs-admin\node_modules\rc-util\es'
console.<computed> @ index.js:1437
index.js:1437 D:/ecodocs-admin/node_modules/rc-util/es/ContainerRender.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-dom' in 'D:\ecodocs-admin\node_modules\rc-util\es'
console.<computed> @ index.js:1437
index.js:1437 D:/ecodocs-admin/node_modules/rc-util/es/Dom/addEventListener.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-dom' in 'D:\ecodocs-admin\node_modules\rc-util\es\Dom'
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this to install react and react-dom:

```
yarn add react react-dom
```

If this not work, you You have to fix the 'externals' configuration in webpack.config :

```
externals: {
   'react': 'react',
   'react-dom': 'react-dom'
}
```

Comment: You just saved me, thank you. But I don't understand, It was working (I had already installed it) It stoped working and it worked again when I added it to externals. Why?

Comment: I discovered it stoped working when I added `alias: { 'react-dom': '@hot-loader/react-dom' }` to the resolve section on my webpack config file. I did it to solve a warning in my browser: `react-hot-loader.development.js:2375 React-Hot-Loader: react--dom patch is not detected. React 16.6+ features may not work`

Answer (score 1):

I think in many cases people will already have react-dom. If so, based on the comments, I think it is worth checking if you have added @hot-loader/react-dom as an alias, but forgot to install it. In such cases you need to do:

```
npm install -D @hot-loader/react-dom
```