# Why can't webpack-cli find modules?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I have a mono-repo using Yarn 3.2.0 Workspaces. It consists of a library and numerous demo projects. The library is responsible for sharing React Components and emits JavaScript and CSS files that are used on front ends.

I get an error stating that the webpack-cli has **failed to load `/path/to/project/webpack.config.js` config**. It then states that it cannot find a particular module. This is always the first module referenced in the `webpack.config.js` file.

I am using a local dev dependency of the CLI:

```
...
"devDependencies": {
  "webpack-cli": "4.9.2"
},
...
```

On build:

```
❯ npm run build

> @ui/library@2.0.0 build
> webpack --config ./webpack.config.js

[webpack-cli] Failed to load '/Users/someone/Workspace/ui/library/webpack.config.js' config
[webpack-cli] Error: Cannot find module 'clean-webpack-plugin'
Require stack:
- /Users/someone/Workspace/ui/library/webpack.config.js
- /Users/someone/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js
- /Users/someone/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/bootstrap.js
- /Users/someone/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js
- /Users/someone/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/lib/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/someone/Workspace/ui/library/webpack.config.js:2:32)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/someone/Workspace/ui/library/webpack.config.js',
    '/Users/someone/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js',
    '/Users/someone/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/bootstrap.js',
    '/Users/someone/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js',
    '/Users/someone/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/lib/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js'
  ]
}
```

---

I removed all Yarn related directories and files and reimplemented using the following steps:

#### Step 1: Install Yarn

Install and use the latest stable version of Yarn (3.2.0) in the root directory.
Now I have `.yarn/releases/yarn-3.2.0.cjs` and `.yarnrc.yml` available.

```
yarn set version stable
```

#### Step 2: .gitignore

Include and exclude the suggested directories in my root `.gitignore` file.

```
# yarn
# https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/qa#which-files-should-be-gitignored
.pnp.*
.yarn/*
!.yarn/patches
!.yarn/plugins
!.yarn/releases
!.yarn/sdks
!.yarn/versions
```

#### Step 3: Install Modules

Go to my UI library directory and install its packages.

```
cd ui/library && yarn install
```

`node_modules` is created in that directory while the `yarn.lock` file is created in the root directory.

#### Step 4: Build Library

I get the same error when I run the build script from the UI library directory.

```
...
"scripts": {
  "build": "webpack --config ./webpack.config.js"
},
...
```

I get hundreds of errors where packages cannot be resolved when I build from the root directory.

```
...
"scripts": {
  "build": "yarn workspace ui/library build"
},
...
```

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-dom' in '/Users/someone/Workspace/ui/library/.yarn/__virtual__/react-transition-group-virtual-931cbef6a8/0/cache/react-transition-group-npm-4.4.2-5052c30656-b67bf5b3e8.zip/node_modules/react-transition-group/esm'
 @ ../.yarn/__virtual__/react-bootstrap-virtual-66bfa60127/0/cache/react-bootstrap-npm-2.1.2-07d2b1a54e-68abcd9dfb.zip/node_modules/react-bootstrap/esm/Collapse.js 4:0-87 25:3-9 26:3-10 27:3-11 28:3-10
```

I am not quite sure what other information to provide. Unfortunately I don't have a repository to share. I'll try create one.

Comment: I couldn't replicate the 'clean-webpack-plugin' issue. I probably I had to uninstall and reinstall it. The issue with 'react-dom' is solved by declaring it in my externals key in the `webpack.config.js` file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62151578/module-not-found-cant-resolve-react-dom. Things must've broken with a combination of somethings I did and I can't pin point what those somethings are.